# Page Viewer Webpart Hides the Top Navigation Menu

Tags: navigation, top-link-bar, hidden, page-viewer-web-part

I have added a page viewer webpart and pointed it to a network share.  The top navigation menu now hides behind this webpart.

I have tried setting the z-index on the menu container as well as the webpart div container.  Nothing that I have tried seems to work.  Has anyone run into this?

Answer (score 3):

ActiveX components (which is what you get rendering a network drive) is always on top of HTML, z-index or not. You cannot do anything about that in Internet Explorer (except having a script that temporarily hides the ActiveX while you're activating your menu).

Comment: You beat me 2 it :-D

Answer (score 1):

An network share is displayed using an ActiveX control (explorer view), which always render on top of everything.